# why matplotlib color bar do not show any tick marks and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I've been trying to plot shape-file polygons with colors according to some data  and add a color-bar. Below shown is the code that I've written for the purpose. It give the plot correctly, but there is no labels or tick marks for the color-bar.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,10), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
ptchs1   = []
for nshp in indx[0,:]:
    ptchs   = []
    pts     = np.array(shapes[nshp].points)
    pts     =pts[np.unique(np.where(~np.isnan(pts[:,:]))[0]),:]
    prt     = shapes[nshp].parts
    par     = list(prt) + [pts.shape[0]]
    for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
        ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]]))
        ptchs1.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]]))
    ind=np.where(indx==nshp)[1] ; 
    ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs,facecolor=my_cmap[np.where(indx==nshp)[1],:],edgecolor='k', linewidths=.5),ccrs.PlateCarree())
    plt.text(xtext[ind], ytext[ind],dnme[ind][0:7],fontsize=8,color='k',fontweight='bold', ha='center',va='center',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_xlim(np.round(mnbbx[0]).astype(int)-0.5,np.round(mxbbx[2]).astype(int)+0.5,2)
ax.set_ylim(np.round(mnbbx[1]).astype(int)-0.5,np.round(mxbbx[3]).astype(int)+0.5,2) 
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
m.set_array([])
m.set_clim(-0.5, 14+0.5) 
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right",aspect=20,size="5%",pad=0.05,map_projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())    
cb=fig.colorbar(m,cax=cax,norm=norm)
cb.set_ticks(np.arange(0,14))
cb.set_label('RainFall(mm/day)', rotation=90)   
cb.set_ticklabels([1,5,10,20,30,40,70,100,130,160,190,220,250])
xticks = np.arange(np.round(mnbbx[0]).astype(int)-0.5,np.round(mxbbx[2]).astype(int)+0.5,2)
yticks = np.arange(np.round(mnbbx[1]).astype(int)-0.5,np.round(mxbbx[3]).astype(int)+0.5,2)

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),draw_labels=True,linewidth=0.7, color='black', alpha=1)
gl.xlabels_bottom = False ;     gl.ylabels_right = False
degree_locator = mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=4) #it will give gridlines of 4*4 size
gl.xlocator = degree_locator
gl.ylocator = degree_locator
_DEGREE_SYMBOL = u'\u00B0'
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER #it will change lon to degree format
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 12, 'color': 'black'} # here we can adjust color and size of ticks
gl.xlabel_style = {'color': 'black', 'size': 12 }
plt.show()
```

Can any one help me that why no color-bar tick mark and labels are not produced?
[image]

I have updated my color bar plotting with this piece of code, it plots correctly, but the main plot and color bar size is different (either big or small)

```
    col_bnd=[0,1,   5,  10,  20,  30,  40,  70, 100, 130, 160, 190, 220, 250,300]
    norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(col_bnd, cmap.N)
    col_bnd=[1,   5,  10,  20,  30,  40,  70, 100, 130, 160, 190, 220, 250]
    ax1, ax2 = mpl.colorbar.make_axes(ax, shrink=0.68,aspect=20,pad=0.05)
    cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1,    cmap=cmap,norm=norm,ticks=col_bnd,boundaries=None,format='%1i') #mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.5, vmax=1.5))
    cbar.set_clim(0, 300)
    cbar.set_label('RainFall(mm/day)', rotation=90)
```

can anyone tell, how to make both main plot and color bar same size?

Answer (score -1):

**[Edit]**

As a commented below, it seems that colorbars need some different way of showing labels. You can try this:

```
cb.set_yticklabels([1,5,10,20,30,40,70,100,130,160,190,220,250])
```

You should call the 'legend' function for each artist you create at your code if you are doing other plottings. For instance, you have the `ax` artist and you set all the necessary info on it, except the legend.
So you should call it before the `plt.show()` so it can generate the legend properly:

```
ax.legend()
fig.legend()
```

And so on.

The documentation has  very good guides for the `legend` and `artists` function:

- http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend
- http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html
- http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html

Comment: He's not creating a legend, but a colorbar

Comment: You're right. From the documentation, colorbars don't need the legend being set, like other plots. From a [code I read](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html), though, you need specify the tick direction of the labeling. In his case, would be something like:
`cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['< -1', '0', '> 1'])`

Comment: You can try putting the `shrink` parameter equal 1.